# RapidMiner reporting chart not fitting

Tags: rapidminer

Hi I am relaive new to RapidMiner,

I am trying to get a good looking report working, using the reporting extension.

When I display a histogram chart, with the standard width and height (800x600) the bottom part is cut off. See [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKac2.jpg)

If I manually change it to 800x800 the chart is displayed correctly. 
The problem is that the chart will changed, based on the input, so I would manually have to check if it fits.

Is there any way to scale the chart to fit the given space e.g. 800x600?

Edit2: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSAgP.jpg) is how the `Report` operator and the `Generate Report` operator are set up:

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. The `Report` operator allows image widths and heights to be specified.

Comment: Thank you awchisholm for trying to help. 
As I said, when having the default value set to 800x600 the chart is cut instead of being resized. 
When I manually set the width and height in the `Report` operator to 800x800 the chart is not cutted.

Comment: What have you set up in the `Generate Report` operator before the `Report` operator?

Comment: I edited my original post. I could not post more than two links, so I had to combine the pictures. 
I only changed text stylings in the `Generate Report` operator, but even with the original settings it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that the page settings in `Generate Report` are for portrait mode whilst the settings in the `Report` operator are for landscape. If you change image width to 600 and image height to 800 in the `Report` operator, I suspect this might resolve the issue for you.

It is confusing however, I noticed that `Generate Report` ignores changes to the page size settings - this is likely to be a bug. It's also confusing that increasing the image dimensions shrinks the rendered image. I'm afraid it's trial and error. I don't think the image will change between runs, the size is fixed by the dimensions you give it.

Comment: When I changed it to 600x800 it is shown correctly. However I still can't make the image smaller to place e.g. text right under it. What is also weird is that when I try different settings, they all seem to break the image.

Comment: What happens if you change the dimensions to 1600 by 1200?

Comment: Hey, now it has the size I want it to. Do I have to increase the resolution in order to get a smaller chart?

Comment: It is confusing as I said in the answer, but it looks like increasing the dimensions shrinks the images. I don't know why but with trial and error perhaps you can get something close to what you want.